# Help with asus p5n-d

Tags: 64-bit

I can't get the 64 bit ubuntu to install I have a ASUS P5N-D. It says "PANIC: early exception 06 rip 10: ffffffff81af2476 error 0 cr2 f0a 788" when trying to boot.

Comment: booting what ? the desktop cd or post-install ? If from the cd, check the integrity of the download https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: I have downloaded the iso and burned the image to a cd. I get the error right before if it will give you the option to try or install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing the 32-bit and after I did that the 64-bit install CDs would run and it let me install. Does anyone know why that made it work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a bad burn or the downloaded iso is corrupt. Check the md5sum of the iso from the link I gave you and if it looks good try another burn.

FWIW you need to "burn" this iso image onto a CD and not copy it.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

There are reports of similar boot errors with hardware problems (faulty ram , faulty power supply) but I am assuming your computer "works"

Comment: It works I had xp installed and running before this